# Datetime picker is not working

Tags: jquery, datetime, picker

This is my whole code.. there is error..datetime picker is not opened on click on textbox..

```
      <script src="/jquery.js"></script>
       <script src="/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>

          <script>
         jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
          </script>
       <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
```

and this is my js .....

```
             jQuery('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                lang:'de',
                 i18n:{
                  de:{
                 months:[
            'Januar','Februar','März','April',
               'Mai','Juni','Juli','August',
           'September','Oktober','November','Dezember',
            ],
              dayOfWeek:[
            "So.", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", 
           "Do", "Fr", "Sa.",
            ]
                   }
                  },
           timepicker:false,
             format:'d.m.Y'
                 });
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure that the both **jquery.datetimepicker.js** and **jquery.datetimepicker.css** are included properly. If not you can get it from [DateTimePicker Git Repo](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker).

And now moving on to your issue , you are initializing the datetimepicker two time.

First using ,

```
 jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
```

And secondly using ,

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                lang:'de',
                 i18n:{
                  de:{
                 months:[
            'Januar','Februar','März','April',
               'Mai','Juni','Juli','August',
           'September','Oktober','November','Dezember',
            ],
              dayOfWeek:[
            "So.", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", 
           "Do", "Fr", "Sa.",
            ]
                   }
                  },
           timepicker:false,
             format:'d.m.Y'
                 });
```

And in the latter case you are using wrong **selector id** i.e `datetimepicker1`.

So moving on to the solution  , use one initialization instance and inside document ready like ,

```
    $(function(){
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                     ........
                     // options here
                     .........
         });});
```

### And , here is the [Working Demo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hu4Rg/)

P.S

Before you use a plug-in go through the documentation [here](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/).
And it is not a part of `jquery-ui`.

If the issue still persists try using newer version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You're js is referencing

```
id="datetimepicker1"
```

but the input's

```
id="datetimepicker".
```

Try wrapping your code like this.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker(); 
    });
```